# Where to start in music creation (virtual DJ)?

Tags: audio, music

I want to make music, but I'm very big newbie here. I don't know anything about the software and the proccess of music creation. So:

1. Is this the forum where I can ask my questions about music creation?
2. What is the easiest software where I can start my virtual music creation?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Daria, the first part of your question should be asked on meta AVP - questions about the site. The second part is a bit too subjective though.

Comment: Just to clarify, you could start with garageband on iPad, or Cubase or .... the question isn't really answerable with a definite answer, as everyone will have a preferred option. I would suggest picking a free one, and seeing how it goes. If you then have particular issues, asking about them would be much more appropriate here.

Comment: Hey daria! We need some extra information before we can give you a decent answer. What kind of OS do you use? Do you plan on recording audio? What kind of music do you plan on making? Do you have a budget to spend some cash? Do you already have instruments or a soundcard? If you're interested in EDM production, I'd recommend checking this out http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/i-want-to-learn-how-to-make-electronic-music-where-do-i-start.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of music you want to do:

1. Remix/mashup other people's music to create new songs? --> VirtualDJ
2. Create your own songs --> Any DAW; Live, Reason, Cubase, FLStudio (My favorite)

To achieve the best means of music production in VirtualDJ, it is beneficial to have external hardware to use with it- i.e. your own DJ controllers. If you're trying to remix in VirtualDJ with only a mouse and keyboard... that's going to be a challenge.

To answer your questions:

1. I would say yes.
2. Easiest? I would say Garage Band for Mac. This is based on opinion though.